# Activity restarts after showing the Interestial Ad from Admob

Tags: java, android, admob

I have this app, I am showing an Interestial Ad from Admob in it. it is tests app, when i start a test and start answering on questions the idea is i can evaluate the questions and i see the results at the end, i can press previous to edit my choices. it works fine offline (no ads). but if i activate internet and Interestial Ad starts shows up, i lose all previous evaluated questions. only situation when i don't lose them if pause the test before the Interestial Ad pops up.
I need to keep questions evaluated even the ad pops up and i close it

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    preDestroy();
}

private void preDestroy(){
    Log.d("TestActivity","On Stop");

    if(!canStop){
        finish();
        return;
    }
    if(!isReadonly)
        showDialog("Saving progress...");

    if(!isReadonly){
        if(!isTestMode){
            isDone = true;
        }
        if(isDone) {
            for (int x = 0; x < questions.size(); ++x) {
                Question q = questions.get(x);

                if (!isTestMode && q != null && !evaluatedQuestions.contains(q.getQuestionID())) {
                    questions.remove(x);
                    --x;
                } else if (!isReadonly && isTestMode) {
                    evaluateQuestion(true, q);
                }
            }
        }


        synchronized (TestActivity.this) {
            if (!isReadonly) {
                db.finalizeSession(sessionID, questions, isDone, currentIndex + 1, timeRemaining);
            }
        }
    }

    if(!isReadonly) {
        new CountDownTimer(800, 800) {
            @Override
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onFinish() {
                finish();
            }
        }.start();
    }else{
        finish();
    }
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy(){
    if(dialog!=null) {
        dialog.dismiss();
    }
    super.onDestroy();
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    Log.d("TestActivity","On resume");

    nextButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.next_button);
    backButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.back_button);
    nextButtonView = findViewById(R.id.nextBtnContainer);
    preButtonView = findViewById(R.id.backBtnContainer);
    nextButtonView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (isTestMode) {
                if (currentIndex + 1 != questions.size()) {
                    showNext();
                } else {
                    finalizeSession();
                }
            } else {
                if (evaluatedQuestions.contains(getCurrentQuestion().getQuestionID())) {
                    if (currentIndex + 1 != questions.size()) {
                        showNext();
                    } else {
                        finalizeSession();
                    }
                } else {
                    QuestionFragment questionFragment = (QuestionFragment) adapter.fragments.get(currentIndex);
                    evaluateQuestion(true,questionFragment.getQuestion());
                    questionFragment.evaluateQuestionUI(true);
                }
            }
        }
    });

    preButtonView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            showPrevious();
        }
    });

    if(canStop) {
        populateQuestions();
        if (questions.size() == 0) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "No questions available", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            finish();
            return;
        }


        filterQuestions();
    }else{
        canStop = true;
    }

    new CountDownTimer(500, 500) {
        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {
            if(dialog!=null)
                dialog.dismiss();
        }
    }.start();
}


public class FixedSpeedScroller extends Scroller {
    private int mDuration = 1000;

    public FixedSpeedScroller(Context context){
        super(context);
    }

    public FixedSpeedScroller(Context context, Interpolator interpolator){
        super(context, interpolator);
    }

    public FixedSpeedScroller(Context context, Interpolator interpolator, boolean flywheel){
        super(context, interpolator, flywheel);
    }

    @Override
    public void startScroll(int startX, int startY, int dx, int dy, int duration){
        // Ignore received duration, use fixed one instead
        if(onClickAnim) {
            Log.d("Anim","Other");
            super.startScroll(startX, startY, dx, dy, mDuration);
        }else{
            Log.d("Anim","Default");
            super.startScroll(startX, startY, dx, dy, duration);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void startScroll(int startX, int startY, int dx, int dy){
        if(onClickAnim) {
            Log.d("Anim","Other");
            super.startScroll(startX, startY, dx, dy, mDuration);
        }else{
            Log.d("Anim","Default");
            super.startScroll(startX,startY,dx,dy);
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: can you post your logcat output?

Comment: im testing the app in the phone, i have issue with logcat

Comment: no I told you to post the error which appears in the logcat .

Comment: i know what you mean, there is no error shows up

Comment: Use should not just copy and paste your entire code here, It becomes time consuming for us to read all the code and then find the relevant part. Just paste the code of the part where you are getting error, which in your case will be the interstitial ad code.

Comment: sorry i edited the code, left only th part responsible for the issue

Answer (score 0):

Interstitial ad is an activity. So, after closing that previous activity's (from where the interstitial ad is shown) onResume method will be fired. You have coded inside onResume method which is loading your questions.
Two way to solve this-

1. Need to remove question loading code from onResume method. You can place this inside onCreate and using variables as static.
2. Declare a static variable which will keep track interstitial ad is showing or not. Then check inside onResume that activity is resuming from interstitial or not and code according your need.

Comment: But onResume method gets applied only if i pause the test, while i answer on questions and the ad pops up and i close it, it goes back to the same question before the ad pops up, which means the resume not applied, but the questions i answered before the ad pops up, all of them get reinstated= unanswered

Answer (score 0):

You need to understand the Android Activity lifecycle. You should be storing your Activity's state when it is paused, and refreshing it when it is resumed.

See https://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/index.html